# Create a popup container that distinguishes each button (so they don't all popup at once)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm usually good with searching for my answer, but I can't seem to get this right. The setup I have for this pop-up is perfect (responsive, plays well with what's inside (shortcode) etc.) the problem I'm having is because I've retrofitted from a codepen, it's made for just 1 pop-up per page.

I'm trying to create a project gallery wherein they click an anchor and a container with a slider inside shows the project's work (it works perfectly, just for one popup) but with say potentially 15 project galleries (pop-ups) per page.

I'm a novice with regards to jQuery, so please be easy on me I am ALWAYS learning.

The HTML

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  //open popup
  $('.popup-trigger').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.popup').addClass('is-visible');

  });
     

  //close popup
  $('.popup').on('click', function(event){
    if( $(event.target).is('.popup-close') || $(event.target).is('.popup') ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).removeClass('is-visible');
    }
  });
  //close popup when clicking the esc keyboard button
  $(document).keyup(function(event){
      if(event.which=='27'){
        $('.popup').removeClass('is-visible');
      }
    });
});
});
```

```css
@media(max-width:1150px) {
  .popup-container{
    top: 25% !important;
    width: 90% !important;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 2rem !important;
  }
}
.page-id-474 main#content{
    margin: 0px !important
}
.popup-trigger {
  width: 170px;
  right: 2rem;
  margin: 3em auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding:1rem 2rem;
  text-decoration:none;
  transition:300ms all;
}

.popup-trigger:hover {
    opacity:.8;
}
.popup1 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(56, 56, 55, 0.9);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition:500ms all;

}

.popup1.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
 transition:1s all;
}
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(56, 56, 55, 0.9);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition:500ms all;

}

.popup.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
 transition:1s all;
}

.popup-container {
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  transition:500ms all;
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 2em auto;
  top: 5%;
  padding:5rem;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: .25em .25em .4em .4em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.is-visible .popup-container {
  transform:translateY(0);
  transition:500ms all;
}

.popup-container .popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  font-size:0;
  right: 8px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}


.popup-container .popup-close::before,
.popup-container .popup-close::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #8f9cb5;
}

.popup-container .popup-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 8px;
}

.popup-container .popup-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 8px;
}


.popup-container .popup-close:hover:before,
.popup-container .popup-close:hover:after {
  background-color:#35a785;
  transition:300ms all;
}
/*==========================================================================
    Site grid
==========================================================================  */

.grid-this {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(260px, 1fr));
    padding: 30px;
}
.grid-this.with-spacing {
    gap: 30px;
}
.grid-this .block img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* Grid spacing in slick slider */

.grid-this.with-spacing .slick-slide {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.grid-this.with-spacing .slick-list {
    margin-right: -30px;
}

@media(max-width:1150px) {
    .grid-this.with-spacing .slick-slide {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .grid-this.with-spacing .slick-list {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
.page-id-324    .site-container{
        padding-left: 8px !important;
    padding-right: 8px !important;
    }
}



/* -------------------------------------------------------------
/
/ Main Cat Container
/
/ -------------------------------------------------------------*/
.main-cat-container{
    Padding: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color:#e9ecf2;
    transition:all 1s ease !important;
}

.main-cat-container:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
transition:all 1s ease !important;
}

.main-cat-title{
    padding-top: 12px;
    font-size:22px;
    color:#38507b;
    text-align: center;
}
.main-cat-container:hover i{
color:#0e1932;
}   
.mc-icons{
    text-align: center;
}
.mc-icons i{
    font-size:45px;
}
.choice-p{
    color:#343a40;
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.custom-hr-spacing{
    margin-top: 45px !important;
    margin-bottom: 45px !important;
}
.faux-btn-container{
    text-align: center !important;
    margin-top: 20px !important;
}

.faux-btn{
    
    background-color:#4cb150;
    padding: 15px 35px;
    color: #FFF;
    transition:all 1s ease !important;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.faux-btn:hover{
    background-color:#59cf5d;
    transition:all 1s ease !important;
}
```

```html
<div  class="grid-this with-spacing margins-fix">
<div>
<a href="#0" id="info" class="info popup-trigger" title="info">
<div style="padding-bottom: 50px;" class="main-cat-container">
<div class="mc-icons" data-aos="flip-left"  data-aos-delay="50" aos-duration="500"><img src="https://gilbert.level10designdev.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Gilbert-Design-Build-Before-After-Kitchen-Remodel-Bradenton-Florida.jpg" width=100% height=auto></div>
<h3 class="main-cat-title">vEITH</h3>

<div class="faux-btn-container"><span class="faux-btn">See Project</span></div>
</div> 
</a>
<div class="popup" role="alert">
  <div class="popup-container">
    <a href="#0" class="popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
   [metaslider id="2409"]
  </div> 
</div> 
</div>
<div><a href="#0" id="info" class="info popup-trigger" title="info">

<div style="padding-bottom: 50px;" class="main-cat-container">
<div class="mc-icons" data-aos="flip-left"  data-aos-delay="50" aos-duration="500"><img src="https://gilbert.level10designdev.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Gilbert-Design-Build-Before-After-Kitchen-Remodel-Bradenton-Florida.jpg" width=100% height=auto></div>
<h3 class="main-cat-title">vEITH</h3>

<div class="faux-btn-container"><span class="faux-btn">See Project</span></div>
</div> 
</a>
<div class="popup" role="alert">
  <div class="popup-container">
    <a href="#0" class="popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
   [metaslider id="2409"]
  </div> 
</div> 
</div>
<div>.</div>
</div>
```

I've also created a code pen to visually show you the issue:

https://codepen.io/John_Barbagallo/pen/dyVXOvV

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your html code has a syntax error. The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element. The value of the id attribute must be unique within the HTML document. See [details](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp)

Why are you nesting these 2 pieces of code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            
     })
})
```

I think you should remove the part of the code that is duplicated.

`$('.popup').addClass('is-visible');` this code means that all html elements containing the class `popup` will be added an `is-visible` class. This is lead to your error.

You should [Jquery traversing](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) to find `popup` belong to project clicked
Change it like this:

```
$('.popup-trigger').on('click', function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     $(this).parent().find('.popup').addClass('is-visible');
});
```

All code here:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //open popup
    $('.popup-trigger').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().find('.popup').addClass('is-visible');
    });

    //close popup
    $('.popup').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.popup-close') || $(event.target).is('.popup') ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });

    //close popup when clicking the esc keyboard button
    $(document).keyup(function(event){
        if(event.which=='27'){
            $('.popup').removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
    @media(max-width:1150px) {
        .popup-container{
            top: 25% !important;
            width: 90% !important;
            height: 50%;
            padding: 2rem !important;
        }

    }
    .page-id-474 main#content{
        margin: 0px !important
    }
    .popup-trigger {
        width: 170px;
        right: 2rem;
        margin: 3em auto;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 18px;
        padding:1rem 2rem;
        text-decoration:none;
        transition:300ms all;
    }

    .popup-trigger:hover {
        opacity:.8;
    }
    .popup1 {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1000;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(56, 56, 55, 0.9);
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition:500ms all;

    }

    .popup1.is-visible {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        transition:1s all;
    }
    .popup {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1000;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(56, 56, 55, 0.9);
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition:500ms all;

    }

    .popup.is-visible {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        transition:1s all;
    }

    .popup-container {
        transform:translateY(-50%);
        transition:500ms all;
        position: relative;
        width: 60%;
        margin: 2em auto;
        top: 5%;
        padding:5rem;
        background: #FFF;
        border-radius: .25em .25em .4em .4em;
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    .is-visible .popup-container {
        transform:translateY(0);
        transition:500ms all;
    }

    .popup-container .popup-close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        font-size:0;
        right: 8px;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
    }


    .popup-container .popup-close::before,
    .popup-container .popup-close::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 12px;
        width: 14px;
        height: 3px;
        background-color: #8f9cb5;
    }

    .popup-container .popup-close::before {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        left: 8px;
    }

    .popup-container .popup-close::after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        right: 8px;
    }


    .popup-container .popup-close:hover:before,
    .popup-container .popup-close:hover:after {
        background-color:#35a785;
        transition:300ms all;
    }
    /*==========================================================================
        Site grid
    ==========================================================================  */

    .grid-this {
        width: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(260px, 1fr));
        padding: 30px;
    }
    .grid-this.with-spacing {
        gap: 30px;
    }
    .grid-this .block img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    /* Grid spacing in slick slider */

    .grid-this.with-spacing .slick-slide {
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
    .grid-this.with-spacing .slick-list {
        margin-right: -30px;
    }

    @media(max-width:1150px) {
        .grid-this.with-spacing .slick-slide {
            margin-right: 0;
        }
        .grid-this.with-spacing .slick-list {
            margin-right: 0;
        }
        .page-id-324    .site-container{
            padding-left: 8px !important;
            padding-right: 8px !important;
        }
    }



    /* -------------------------------------------------------------
    /
    / Main Cat Container
    /
    / -------------------------------------------------------------*/
    .main-cat-container{
        Padding: 0px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 3px;
        border-color:#e9ecf2;
        transition:all 1s ease !important;
    }

    .main-cat-container:hover{
        box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 13px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        transition:all 1s ease !important;
    }

    .main-cat-title{
        padding-top: 12px;
        font-size:22px;
        color:#38507b;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .main-cat-container:hover i{
        color:#0e1932;
    }
    .mc-icons{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .mc-icons i{
        font-size:45px;
    }
    .choice-p{
        color:#343a40;
        font-size:22px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .custom-hr-spacing{
        margin-top: 45px !important;
        margin-bottom: 45px !important;
    }
    .faux-btn-container{
        text-align: center !important;
        margin-top: 20px !important;
    }

    .faux-btn{

        background-color:#4cb150;
        padding: 15px 35px;
        color: #FFF;
        transition:all 1s ease !important;
        border-radius: 8px;
    }
    .faux-btn:hover{
        background-color:#59cf5d;
        transition:all 1s ease !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-this with-spacing margins-fix">
    <div>
        <a href="#0" id="project01" class="info popup-trigger" title="info">

            <div style="padding-bottom: 50px;" class="main-cat-container">
                <div class="mc-icons" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-delay="50" aos-duration="500"><img
                        src="https://gilbert.level10designdev.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Gilbert-Design-Build-Before-After-Kitchen-Remodel-Bradenton-Florida.jpg"
                        width=100% height=auto></div>
                <h3 class="main-cat-title">vEITH</h3>

                <div class="faux-btn-container"><span class="faux-btn">See Project</span></div>
            </div>
        </a>

        <div class="popup" role="alert">
            <div class="popup-container">
                <a href="#0" class="popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
                [project01]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div>
        <a href="#0" id="project02" class="info popup-trigger" title="info">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 50px;" class="main-cat-container">
            <div class="mc-icons" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-delay="50" aos-duration="500"><img
                    src="https://gilbert.level10designdev.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Gilbert-Design-Build-Before-After-Kitchen-Remodel-Bradenton-Florida.jpg"
                    width=100% height=auto></div>
            <h3 class="main-cat-title">vEITH</h3>

            <div class="faux-btn-container"><span class="faux-btn">See Project</span></div>
        </div>
    </a>
        <div class="popup" role="alert">
            <div class="popup-container">
                <a href="#0" class="popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
                [project02]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>.</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Lam Tran Duc, thank you for this!

Comment: If my answer helpful with you, upvote or accept it please.

Answer (score 0):

Hi what you need is to get the clicker, then find the pop in the parent of the clicker  see below:

```js
//open popup
$('.popup-trigger').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // Next line is what changed.
  $(this).parent().find(".popup").addClass('is-visible');
});
```